# How to open 'About Mozilla Firefox' (update) window with one command

Tags: linux, command-line, firefox, software-updates, window

For some reason I have ended up using the 'local' (portable) version of Firefox, and it can check for updates from its dedicated window (Help - About...).

[image]

Can that window be opened with one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific Firefox option or URL to open that specific window that I am aware of but you can automate key strokes to open that window using:

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --class firefox windowactivate --sync key --delay 500 Alt+h a
```

That will search for a visible Firefox window, focus the window and send the necessary key strokes.

Adjust the delay between keystrokes if required.

Comment: All problems that command causes on my keys are fixed by reboot, which means that  the command runs in background or makes changes that are reset only by reboot. (maybe `xdotool` is buggy on my Kubuntu 22.04? Was not even installed by default.)

Comment: Automating key strokes across different environments can be a hit or miss. It seems the `windowfocus` command in `xdotool` is buggy in Kubuntu 22.04. I initially had it set to `windowactivate` instead since that worked in Arch with i3 but when I tested it in Fedora 36 with GNOME, it failed to work properly so I changed it to `windowfocus` because that worked for both systems. However, `windowactivate` does work with Kubuntu. The `--sync` option is also required to prevent interfering with the Super key. The modified command above should work properly on Kubuntu 22.04 as tested myself.